# Android doesn't show AlertDialog in OnActivityResult

Tags: android, android-camera, android-alertdialog, onactivityresult

The user is able to take a picture with the camera using this method:

```
  private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION, ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, Constants.REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }
```

In the OnActivityResult I want to present 2 different versions of the taken image which were edited with JNI. So I am trying to show an AlertDialog:

```
  AlertDialog.Builder alertadd = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            final View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.dialog_segmen, null);
            ImageView iv1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            ImageView iv2 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

            ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
            imageLoader.displayImage("file:///" + outputWahetFile, iv1);
            imageLoader.displayImage("file:///" + outputCahtFile, iv2);

            alertadd.setView(view);
            alertadd.setNeutralButton("Here!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int sumthin) {

                }
            });
            alertadd.create().show();
```

But nothing happens at all. No errors, no dialog, nothing. This applies also for a non customized dialog like this:

```
   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("message")
                    .setTitle("title");
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
```

The whole onActivityResult()

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

            String id = "" + System.currentTimeMillis();

            File inputDir = new File(getFilesDir() + File.separator + mUserMail + Constants.DIR_INPUT);
            inputDir.mkdirs();
            File inputFile = new File(inputDir + File.separator + id + Constants.END_JPG);

            File textureDir = new File(getFilesDir() + File.separator + mUserMail + Constants.DIR_TEXTURE + File.separator + id);
            textureDir.mkdirs();
            File textureWahetFile = new File(textureDir + File.separator + USITHelper.ALGO_SEG_WAHET_SHORT + Constants.END_PNG);
            File textureCahtFile = new File(textureDir + File.separator + USITHelper.ALGO_SEG_CAHT_SHORT + Constants.END_PNG);

            File output = new File(getFilesDir() + File.separator + mUserMail + Constants.DIR_SEGMENTS + File.separator + id);
            output.mkdirs();
            File outputWahetFile = new File(output + File.separator + USITHelper.ALGO_SEG_WAHET_SHORT + Constants.END_JPG);
            File outputCahtFile = new File(output + File.separator + USITHelper.ALGO_SEG_CAHT_SHORT + Constants.END_JPG);

            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(inputFile);
                imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 99, fos);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            IrisEntry e = new IrisEntry();
            e.setId(id);
            e.setUserId(mUserMail);
            mUSITHelper.segmentPicture(inputFile, textureWahetFile, outputWahetFile, USITHelper.ALGO_SEG_WAHET_SHORT);
            mUSITHelper.segmentPicture(inputFile, textureCahtFile, outputCahtFile, USITHelper.ALGO_SEG_CAHT_SHORT);

            /////// APPROACH ONE - standard dialog
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("message")
                    .setTitle("title");
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();

            /////// APPROACH TWO - custom dialog
            AlertDialog.Builder alertadd = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            final View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.dialog_segmen, null);
            ImageView iv1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            ImageView iv2 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

            ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
            imageLoader.displayImage("file:///" + outputWahetFile, iv1);
            imageLoader.displayImage("file:///" + outputCahtFile, iv2);

            alertadd.setView(view);
            alertadd.setNeutralButton("Here!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int sumthin) {

                }
            });
            alertadd.create().show();

            /////// APPROACH THREE- dialog activity
            Intent i = new Intent(this, SegmentationDialog.class);
            i.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_CAHT_PATH, outputCahtFile.getPath());
            i.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_WAHET_PATH, outputWahetFile.getPath());
            startActivityForResult(i, Constants.REQUEST_SEGEMNTATION_CHOOSE);

            addItem(e);
        }

        if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_SEGEMNTATION_CHOOSE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


        }

        if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_SEGEMNTATION_CHOOSE && resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            dispatchTakePictureIntent();
        }
    }
```

I tired each of the three different approaches on it's own (not combined). The only working approach for the moment is the custom dialog Activity, but I would like to continue working with my already existing IrisEntry object

Comment: Is onActivityResult() called? Check this with logging or something.

Comment: Or use debug mode to see if code is called

Comment: please post your onActivtyResult() method

Comment: Yes method and code are called. I'll add the whole method

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. You display an AlertDialog and then immediately start a new Activity?

Comment: It is just the three approaches. I tried every single one without the others. When the activity isn't started I still get back to the plain MainActivity

Comment: What is launch mode of your activity? Is "Dont Keep activities" in developer options on Your testing device disabled? Sry for bad English.

Comment: Yes it is disabled. I somehow have the feeling that there are two threads running. But I don't know why

Comment: Try to log the process with `adb logcat -v threadtime` and you will see if `onActivityResult()` runs on the UI thread (as it is expected). Another suggestion: try to create the AlertDialog before launching camera, and in `onActivityResult()` only use **alertDialog.show()**.

Comment: Actually I need to do stuff with the taken picture which is then displayed in the dialog so that's not possible. I will check threads like this later